# How to use a service class in a controller class?

Tags: php, oop, zend-framework, class, zend-framework-mvc

I'm trying to integrate [this amazing calendar](http://www.arietis-software.com/blog/index.php/2009/05/26/calendar-class-based-on-zend_date/)  in my project. I get trouble with the service thing. I'm using this kind of structure:

```
application/
    modules/
        agenda/
            controllers/
                CalendarController.php
            models/
            services/
                CalendarService.php
            views/
                filters/
                helpers/
                scripts/
                calendar/
                    view-calendar.php
    module2/
    module3/
```

I route this in my application.ini this way:

```
resources.router.routes.agenda.route = /apps/agenda/
resources.router.routes.agenda.defaults.module = agenda
resources.router.routes.agenda.defaults.controller = calendar
resources.router.routes.agenda.defaults.action = view
```

I pointed my browser on, and I obtained this message:

```
Message: Invalid controller class ("Agenda_CalendarController")
```

I fixed it with my Agenda_ suffix and refreshed my browser. Obtained this:

```
Message: Controller "Agenda_CalendarController" is not an instance of Zend_Controller_Action_Interface
```

So I instanced it with "extends Zend_Controller_Action". Obtained this: :-)

```
Fatal error: Class 'Service_Calendar' not found in /home/[PATH TO MY APP FOLDER]/application/modules/agenda/controllers/CalendarController.php on line 30
```

I can't figure out what's going wrong. Someone have a hint or two for me :-)

Note: I do not know if that means anything, but I use NetBeans and if I press CTRL while hover a class method of service in the controller class; related popup informations are correct.

Solution:
Thanks guys, You gave me the path to go further. My modules bootstraping wasn't set properly. with your hints I found this post from Bob Allen, where he describes the same problem.

When you know what you're searching for... :-)

Thanks, my problem is fixed and I know a bit more!

Comment: Try moving `application/modules/agenda/services/CalendarService.php` to `application/services/Calendar.php` and see if it has any luck finding the class.  You may need to rename the class using your application namespace (e.g. Application_Service_Calendar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The naming convention for a controller isn't the same for model/service/view etc., in the sense that you needn't prepend the type in the filename, as you would with a controller. They must follow the basic autoloading name-to-path schema.

So, the declaration for you service would be: `Agenda_Service_CalendarService`, because that maps to `modules/agenda/services/CalendarService.php` (note the inflection - from the `services` folder to the `_Service_` singular - that's ZF working and it happens for models, too).

Also make sure you've properly initialized the module (having its own Bootstrap.php file, set up in application.ini).

PS: NetBeans knows where your class is, because it scanned the files and saw the declaration, not the logical inclusion of that class.